# New design makes meta comments invisible on mouseover

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On meta, comment mouseovers turn the background white, which makes the text invisible.

#### Normal comment

[image: Screenshot of a normal comment]

#### Mouseover comment

[image: Screenshot of a mouseover comment]

Comment: Demonstration comment

Comment: i see it.fix is coming soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed. Please verify